# Create an array of repeating elements that increase by 0.1 intervals

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

What I want my code to do is to create an array of elements:
[13.8, 13.9, 14.,...] That increase by 0.1, but each of the elements should repeat 17 times before going on to the next number. Below is my code.

```
from numpy import*
from pylab import*
def f(elem):
return repeat((elem + 0.1),17)
print f(13.8)

def lst(init):
   yield init
   while True:
       next = f(init)
       yield next
       init = next

for i in lst(13.8):
    print i
    if i > 20:
        break
```

The output of code only shows an array 13.9 repeating 17 times, but then it shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repeatelementsarray.py", line 19
    if i > 20:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It seems the program is trying to create more than one array of numbers, I just want one array. Also since lst is a generator it shouldn't give an array, so using fromiter?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`np.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to get the linearly increasing sequence, and [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to repeat each element:

```
import numpy as np

elems = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
reps = np.repeat(elems, 3)

print(reps)
# [ 0.   0.   0.   0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.4  0.4  0.4
#   0.5  0.5  0.5  0.6  0.6  0.6  0.7  0.7  0.7  0.8  0.8  0.8  0.9  0.9  0.9]
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `np.linspace` instead of `np.arange`.  Because of floating point imprecision, it is not unusual for `np.arange` to give an unexpected number of elements.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `np.arange` seems the more natural choice since the OP specified the interval rather than the number of steps. Not sure what you mean by *"unexpected number of elements"*?

Comment: I agree!  But giving a floating point increment to `arange` is prone to off-by-one issues.  For example, I get the same answer for both `arange(13.5, 13.9, 0.1)` and `arange(13.5, 14.0, 0.1)`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It's worth mentioning, but without more info on what the OP is actually trying to do, I'd hesitate to recommend `np.linspace` here.

Comment: Well, having been burned before, I hesitate to recommend `arange` over  `linspace` when the increment is not an integer.  Anyway, you already got my upvote. :-)

Comment: Oh wow that was easy, I'm not sure why I tried to define a new function. Since I know the stepsize is  0.1, it was better for me to use arange. Thanks

Comment: But since 0.1 is not an integer I realize linespace would be better, since arange is better for integer steps. As per numpy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on xrange, you can produce a function like this:

```py
def repeated_range(start, stop, step=0.1, repeat=5):
    r = start
    while r < stop:
        for i in xrange(repeat):
            yield r
        r += step
```

This produces what you want.